# Has No Member Error Issue with JSON Decoder using Structs in Swift

Tags: json, swift, struct, jsondecoder

I used `https://app.quicktype.io/` to create the structs to decode some JSON and it decodes it successfully.

However, when I try to access the elements within the main object, I am getting a has no member error as follows:

```
Value of type 'myClass.BookReturned?' has no member 'title'.
```

This is what the JSON looks like:

```
{"book":[{"title":"Dreams of Trespass","author":"Fatimah Mernisse","pic":""}]}

struct BookReturned: Codable {
        let book: [Book]
    }
    
    //  Book
struct Book: Codable {
        let title, author, pic: String
    }
```

This is what the code looks like with the error occuring on the second line

```
let mybook = try? JSONDecoder().decode(BookReturned.self, from: data)
let author = mybook.title//GIVES THE ERROR
```

What is the proper way to get the title? If the JSON is malformed, I have the ability to change the JSON as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look at the struct `BookReturned`. There is indeed no member `title`.

You have to get the first item of the array `book`, there is the `title`

```
let title = mybook.book.first?.title
```

If the array contains more items you need a loop.